# How to avoid ReactorNotRestartable in Autobahn Python

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn, crossbar

I have a python based page which recieves data by POST, which is then forwarded to the Crossbar server using Autobahn (Wamp). It works well the first 1-2 times but when it's called again after that it throws `ReactorNotRestartable`.

Now, I need this to work whichever way possible, either by reusing this "Reactor" based on a conditional check or by stopping it properly after every run. (The first one would be preferable because it might reduce the execution time)

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

This is in a webpage (**Django View**) so it needs to run as many times as the page is loaded/data is sent to it via POST.

```
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
    from twisted.application.internet import ClientService
    from autobahn.wamp.types import ComponentConfig
    from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession, WampWebSocketClientFactory
    
    class MyAppSession(ApplicationSession):
    
        def __init__(self, config):
            ApplicationSession.__init__(self, config)
    
        def onConnect(self):
            self.join(self.config.realm)
    
        def onChallenge(self, challenge):
            pass
    
        @inlineCallbacks
        def onJoin(self, details):
            yield self.call('receive_data', data=message)
            yield self.leave()
    
        def onLeave(self, details):
            self.disconnect()
    
        def onDisconnect(self):
            reactor.stop()
    
    message = "data from POST[]"

    session = MyAppSession(ComponentConfig('realm_1', {}))

    transport = WampWebSocketClientFactory(session, url='ws://127.0.0.1:8080')
    endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, '127.0.0.1', 8080)
    
    service = ClientService(endpoint, transport)
    service.startService()
    reactor.run()
```

I figured out a probably hacky-and-not-so-good way by using multiprocessing and putting `reactor.stop()` inside `onJoin()` right after the function call. This way I don't have to bother with the "twisted running in the main thread" thing because its process gets killed as soon as my work is done.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Hello.  Please share a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Added the example.